# C# - Save a ListView through the AppSettings

Tags: c#, listview, appsettings

Good evening,

I have set in the AppSettings of my project a ListView object but I have no idea what I should use as value?! Because when I left it blank I can't save anything to my setting property rather the get value is always null after save.  Is it possible to do this with AppSettings actually ?

Thanks for your answers!

Kind regards

Comment: What property do you want to save in your appsettings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you save your listview, could you provide some code?
If you want to persist the state of your listview, you could try the [XMLSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(VS.80).aspx) or the [SoapFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.aspx) to generate the xml and store it in a separate xml file.

Comment: The problem was that a ListView is not serializable. So I fill all the ListViewItems in my "MyEntry"-class and put these in a List<MyEntry> and save this list through BinaryFormatter (Look at SoapFormatter) =).

Comment: Yeah no problem! The programm is running great with BinaryFormatter now ;-) ! Thanks a lot!